# RuntimeError: Input tensor at index 3 has invalid shape [2, 2, 16, 128, 64] but expected [2, 4, 16, 128, 64]

Tags: python, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker, huggingface-transformers, gpt-2

Runtime error while finetuning a pretrained [GPT2-medium](https://huggingface.co/gpt2-medium) model using [Huggingface](https://huggingface.co/transformers/) library in SageMaker - [ml.p3.8xlarge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebooks-available-instance-types.html) instance.

The `finetuning_gpt2_script.py` contains the below,

Libraries:

```
from transformers import Trainer, TrainingArguments
from transformers import EarlyStoppingCallback
from transformers import GPT2LMHeadModel, GPT2Tokenizer
from transformers import TextDataset,DataCollatorForLanguageModeling
```

Pretrained Models:

```
gpt2_model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained("gpt2-medium")
gpt2_tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained("gpt2-medium")
```

Train and Test Data Construction:

```
train_dataset = TextDataset(
          tokenizer=gpt2_tokenizer,
          file_path=train_path,
          block_size=128)
    
test_dataset = TextDataset(
          tokenizer=gpt2_tokenizer,
          file_path=test_path,
          block_size=128)
    
data_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(
        tokenizer=gpt2_tokenizer, mlm=False,
    )
```

`train_path` & `test_path` are unstructured text data file of size 1.45 Million and 200K lines of data

Training arguments:

```
training_args = TrainingArguments(
        output_dir="./gpt2-finetuned-models", #The output directory
        overwrite_output_dir=True, #overwrite the content of the output directory
        num_train_epochs=1, # number of training epochs
        per_device_train_batch_size=8, # batch size for training #32
        per_device_eval_batch_size=8,  # batch size for evaluation #64
        save_steps=100, # after # steps model is saved
        warmup_steps=500,# number of warmup steps for learning rate scheduler
        prediction_loss_only=True,
        metric_for_best_model = "eval_loss",
        load_best_model_at_end = True,
        evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    )
```

`training_args` are the training arguments constructed to train the model.

Trainer:

```
trainer = Trainer(
        model=gpt2_model,
        args=training_args,
        data_collator=data_collator,
        train_dataset=train_dataset,
        eval_dataset=test_dataset,
        callbacks = [early_stop_callback],
    )
early_stop_callback = EarlyStoppingCallback(early_stopping_patience  = 3)
```

Training:

```
trainer.train()
trainer.save_model(model_path)
```

Here, the training is done for only 1 epoch in 4 GPUS using [ml.p3.8xlarge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebooks-available-instance-types.html) instance.

The training is done by torch-distribution like below,

```
python -m torch.distributed.launch finetuning_gpt2_script.py
```

While training at the end of the epoch, observed the below error,

`RuntimeError: Input tensor at index 3 has invalid shape [2, 2, 16, 128, 64] but expected [2, 4, 16, 128, 64]`

1. Is the `RuntimeError` because of the way the `train_dataset` and `test_dataset`constructed using `TextData` ?
2. Am I doing wrong in the `torch-distribution` ?

Answer (score 1):

It could be related to a mismatch in the batch size (expecting a batch size of 4 but receiving a batch size of 2) as suggested [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/1220) ? Solution provided is to set the parameter `drop_last` in your `DataLoader` like this:

```
tain_text = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=args.batch_size, shuffle=True, drop_last=True)
```

Comment: The object type I am using transformers.TextDataSet library to construct the train_text and test_text